# Compiling a binary immune to library redirection on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, g++, static-libraries, static-linking, setuid

I notice that on Mac OS X (currently I am running Yosemite, but I had the same problem on earlier versions of OS X) whenever I invoke **g++** (or even **gcc** for that matter) with the **-static** option, the linking of the binary fails -- always due to some library or another not being successfully found. As a result, I am only able to produce binaries that use shared libraries.

This is a problem, as I have a situation that I can not resolve without writing a program that gets installed with Setuid Root permission. This program I need to write will inspect the environment variables to assure that they are free of any malice (and it will do so with a better-safe-than-sorry attitude) and then it will demote it's user-ID to that of a regular user *before* using a form of *exec()* to invoke another program.

These security checks of the environment will assure that the *other* program can run safely under the assurance that critical environment variables (such as **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**) are not corrupted. But this program *itself* can *not* run under any such assurance - because it is part of it's job to *perform* this check in the *first* place.

So how can I protect this C++ program from such a security vulnerability? My first thought was to compile it with the **-static** option --- but since this does not work on OS X, does anyone have any *other* ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As long as the executable is setuid, the loader kills all DYLD_* environment variables. From [the source code for dyld.cpp](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-210.2.3/src/dyld.cpp):

```
// For security, setuid programs ignore DYLD_* environment variables.
// Additionally, the DYLD_* enviroment variables are removed
// from the environment, so that any child processes don't see them.
```

[original answer:] According to [this post by Sam Marshall](http://www.samdmarshall.com/blog/blocking_code_injection_on_ios_and_os_x.html), you can do it by adding new section to the binary header named  "__RESTRICT", with a section named "__restrict". You can do this in Xcode by adding this to to "Other Linker Flags":

```
-Wl,-sectcreate,__RESTRICT,__restrict,/dev/null
```

The other possible ways to get DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ignored are to have the executable be setuid or setgid, or signed with entitlements. From [the source code for dyld.cpp](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-210.2.3/src/dyld.cpp):

```
dyld::log("dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because ");
switch (sRestrictedReason) {
    case restrictedNot:
        break;
    case restrictedBySetGUid:
        dyld::log("main executable (%s) is setuid or setgid\n", sExecPath);
        break;
    case restrictedBySegment:
        dyld::log("main executable (%s) has __RESTRICT/__restrict section\n", sExecPath);
        break;
    case restrictedByEntitlements:
        dyld::log("main executable (%s) is code signed with entitlements\n", sExecPath);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear how to translate the vague suggestion specified in the first option in this answer into action. I _attempted_ to do as you suggest (assuming I understood correctly) and got the following warning message http://pastebin.com/HGHFTFQu -- and am not sure how exactly to verify that the desired result occurred.

Comment: @Sophia_ES The error message is rather unclear, but I think the problem is that you need to use commas rather than spaces between the parts of the linker option. It also looks like you're using the GNU compiler, and this option may only be supported by Apple's Clang-based linker. But try the commas first, that might be all that's needed.

Comment: Okay --- this time it worked without so much as a squeak --- if I can now just verify that the desired outcome was reached. Oh --- I notice you mentioned that __DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH__ will also be ignored if the executable is setuid or setgid. Are you saying that when I set the executable's permissions to _setuid_, the security concern that I am so worried about is solved automatically --- and that Apple has _already_ taken care of the security concern I am worried about?

Comment: @Sophia_ES D'oh! Yes, I glazed right over the part of your original question where you mentioned it being setuid. Although if you're feeling paranoid, adding the __RESTRICT/__restrict as well shouldn't hurt anything.